# Facebook checkbox rendered but with height and width 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Very strange thing, the messenger checkbox plugin worked as a charm and then stopped from showing.

I'm getting the "Rendered" event fired but the checkbox's iFrame has height and width equal to 0.

If i manually change that, the plugin will become visible.

We also not getting the webhook response.

Any one has an idea where to start?

Here is the relevant code:
Checkbox element:

```
<div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"
      origin="domain"
      page_id="Our page id"
      messenger_app_id="our app id"
      user_ref="UniqueId"
      allow_login="true"
      size="small"
      >
 </div>
```

Events:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId            : 'our app id',
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v2.6'//our webhooks version
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('messenger_checkbox', function(e) {
            if (e.event == 'rendered') {
                console.log("Plugin was rendered");//FIRED EACH TIME!
            } else if (e.event == 'checkbox') {
                if(e.state === "checked") {
                    chkbxplgnSelected = true;
                }
                else
                    chkbxplgnSelected = false;
                console.log("Checkbox state: " + e.state);
            } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
                console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
            } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
                console.log("Plugin was hidden");
            }

        });
    };
```

Things to note:

1. Plugin parent.parent.parent container has a position: fixed on it.
2. When loading the page in developer mode set to Mobile Devices, the following error is showed in the console:

   ```
   (Only on mobile inspection)
   ```

   Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/plugins/messenger_checkbox.php?allow_login=true&app_id=446487378882911&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FFdM1l_dpErI.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df2172ca0fd08e74%26domain%3Dcdn.tictuk.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fcdn.tictuk.com%252Ffea4c513e273dc%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&locale=en_US&messenger_app_id=446487378882911&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.tictuk.com&sdk=joey&size=small': 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: i think i did a javascript that resizes the iframe's Height and Width